# Mapping the standard $(n!-1)$-simplex into $GL_n(\mathbb C)$

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, linear-algebra, gt.geometric-topology, matrices

Let $\Delta^{n!-1}$ be the standard $(n!-1)$-simplex whose vertices are indexed by the elements of the symmetric group $S_n$, that is
\begin{equation}
\Delta^{n!-1} = \left\{ (t_\sigma)_{\sigma\in S_n} \in \mathbb R^{n!} : \sum_{\sigma\in S_n} t_\sigma = 1 \ \textrm{and} \ t_\sigma \geq 0, \forall \sigma\in S_n \right\},
\end{equation}
and let $\{P_\sigma \in GL_n(\mathbb C)\}_{\sigma\in S_n}$ be the permutation matrices.

> **Question:** Does there exist a continuous map $f: \Delta^{n!-1} \rightarrow GL_n(\mathbb C)$ such that for all $(t_\sigma)_{\sigma\in S_n} \in \Delta^{n!-1}$ the non-zero entries of the matrix $f((t_\sigma)_{\sigma\in S_n})$ are supported on the non-zero entries of $\sum_{\sigma\in S_n} t_\sigma P_\sigma$?

This can be done for $n=2$, namely
\begin{equation}
f(t_e + t_{(1,2)}) = \left[\begin{array}{cc} t_e & t_{(1,2)} \\ -t_{(1,2)} & t_e\end{array}\right],
\end{equation}
and $n=3$,
\begin{equation}
f((t_\sigma)_{\sigma\in S_3}) = \left(\sum_{\sigma\in S_3} t_\sigma P_\sigma\right) \circ \left[\begin{array}{ccc} i & 1 & 1\\ 1& i & 1\\ 1& 1 & i\end{array}\right] 
\end{equation}
where $\circ$ denotes the Hadamard or Schur product. This second map is into the invertible matrices since the determinant of the second matrix is $2-4i$ (or $1+1-i-i-i-i$ thinking in terms of the Leibniz formula) and so the determinant will never be zero if you multiply each entry by a non-negative scalar in the fashion of $f$.

Perhaps there is some topological obstruction in higher dimensions?